# Can i successfully send a file(eg: a picture) between two browsers via WebRTC?

Tags: browser, udp, webrtc

So WebRTC uses UDP and it works great if you are doing some video streaming, if you lose few frames that's ok but i wonder how that works when sending files like pictures.

The main problem being that UDP does not verify file integrity like TCP does and just by missing a packet you could end up with a corrupted file.

So how can you send pictures reliable between browsers and ensure that  the files are whole?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the datachannel to transfer files. They provide an abstraction providing reliable transfer. See https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/datachannel/filetransfer/ for a sample.

Comment: that sounds like you do not want webrtc but want users to upload the file once, using http.

Comment: https://file.pizza is an example how to transfer files/images between two hosts using WebRTC